# Adding compact view option to Nautilus on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: nautilus, 19.10

I'm wondering if there is a way to add compact view option to nautilus on ubuntu 19.10. So far there are only two options (and nautilus doesn't even show their names).

Thank you for your willingness.